# Doctrine event listener not executed in Symfony2 data fixtures

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I defined an event listener on the entitymanager ([howto](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-event-listeners/)). But when I'm loading my datafixtures, the event listener methods are not called. Is this behaveour changed in the last Symfony? As I see this post [here](http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2011/06/doctrine-event-listeners-vs-fixtures.html), I think it worked in Symfony 1.4.

**Solved - I made a stupid mistake, I tried to use the "postInsert" event, but this don't exists. "postPersist" is the correct event name**

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, I tried to use the "postInsert" event, but this don't exists. "postPersist" is the correct event name.

Comment: answer your own question an mark it as complete